# Maven project and android dependencies

Tags: android, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Trying to add android dependencies to maven project, but can't get dependencies. Is there something special about fetching android dependencies?

```xml
<repository>
    <id>google</id>
    <url>https://maven.google.com/</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>androidx.appcompat</groupId>
    <artifactId>appcompat</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And error:

```
Cannot resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 <scope>runtime</scope>
```

like this

```
<dependency>
<groupId>androidx.appcompat</groupId>
<artifactId>appcompat</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Still the same: `Cannot resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0`

Comment: Well, that's a good question. Isn't it just a jar which should be downloaded from repository?